# Why does Visual Studio 2010 Express while publishing to FTP copy images in my Content folder to /bin/content/ AND /content/?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build

What should be the correct "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" settings on all images, JavaScript files, and CSS files in my /Content/ folder in my ASP.NET MVC3 web app?

I don't understand why Visual Studio creates duplicates of these files inside the /bin/ folder even when the build action is set to "None"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

To make images and other content copy to the destination while being published, the build action must be set to "Content".

Unless the file should *also* be stored in the /bin/ folder, "Copy to Output Directory" should be left set to "None".